# How to make every button by default look like BS5 btn-outline-secondary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to look every button to look by default like `btn-outline-secondary`

[image: bootstrap5-button-outline-secondary]

See [Bootstrap5 Outline Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons)

Example:

```
<form>
 <button>foo</button>
</form>
```

this button should get the styling like `btn-outline-secondary`.

How can I achieve that?

BUT: I can't modify the HTML snippet, since it gets generated by a library. I would like to use JS/CSS to achieve the goal.

Background: I am using BS5 and don't need to support dated browsers like IE11.

Comment: The obvious answer is add `btn-outline-secondary` to each of your buttons.  But I suppose that's not what you wanted... wich is ... ????  (Give us more info:  Why, Where, Example. and the such...)

Comment: @Vino I updated the question: BUT: I can't modify the HTML snippet, since it gets generated by a library. I would like to use JS/CSS to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```js
(function applyDefaultClassesToButtons() {
   var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
   for (i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.add("btn");
    buttons[i].classList.add('btn-outline-secondary');
   }
})();
```

Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x9fk6rvj/)

Comment: Nice!  (And no jQuery, so works with both BS4 and BS5)

Answer (score 1):

simply apply the style that you take from bootstrap:

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(108 117 125 / 50%);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>foo</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Isn't `btn-outline-secondary`  its own class to copy rather than the base button design in your answer? So it's more like `.btn-outline-secondary, button { .... }` kind of thing

Comment: @Martin I understood that he want to give all the buttons the style of `btn-outline-secondary` but probably it's not the case. Let's wait for his feedback

Comment: I think I know what you've done, in that you've taken the CSS from `.btn-outline-secondary` and hardcoded it into `button{ ... }` but that took me a few minutes to realise (post my above comment). I would have thought that adding the `button` to the `.btn-outline-secondary` ruleset would be better as there's no code repeat and if `btn-outline-secondary` changes then `button` would also update. I guess the only downside is rule ordering, but I just felt that that was more concise...

Comment: @Martin I supposed that he cannot directly edit the boostrap CSS. If it was the case, then the trivial answer is to add `,button` there (you can make it an answer by the way)

Comment: I suspect your method is the best method rather than actually overwriting the Bootstrap code which will be updated in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some CSS preprocessors like LESS or SASS, you could do something like this:

```
button {
    .btn;
    .btn-outline-secondary;
}
```

If not, I think JS is the only right way as @momh answered.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Up to now I have not used LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could simply use your `CSS` with the colors you desire. In this case i think you like the colors of that BS5 button.

```css
button {
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-decoration: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #6c757d;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s cubic-bezier(.23,.97,.83,.67), background-color .15s cubic-bezier(.23,.97,.83,.67), box-shadow .15s cubic-bezier(.23,.97,.83,.67);
  color: #6c757d;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
  border-color: #6c757d;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(108 117 125 / 50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">
<form>
  <button>SAVE</button>
  <button>NEXT</button>
  <button>Secondary</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS preprocessors (I can't write comments as of now), then I would suggest using one, I know that SASS and LESS have a way of [extending](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) selectors. This way you could apply your rule to the the `button` selector.

It is a way better solution than simply copying the rules since the library can change and you probably dont want to check every update whether you should change your selector or not.

And if you want to change only the button in the form, then you might either write a more complex selector, or a better solution would be adding a wrapper around the snippet you can't change.

If CSS preprocessors are out of question, then my answer would be checking out the answer of @Momh